# addEventListener("loadedmetadata",fun) doesn't run correctly ,Firefox misses event

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, events

I wrote a page , and found addEventListener("loadedmetadata",fun) doesn't run correctly on firefox

I'm trying fixing a bug of a old software .While loading video and page, the software try to draw some player-controller on the page .It worked well on Chrome and IE , but fail to draw some player-controller on Firefox .I tried debuging days until I found problem can simplify like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
alert("The vid");
vid.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", getmetadata);

function getmetadata()
{
alert("Meta data for video loaded");
}

</script> 

<p>test</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

I expected firefox(41.0.1) to alert twice with ("The vid") and ("Meta data for video loaded") , but it didn't.
These code run correctly on chrome 45 and IE11 .Both of these browers alert twice with ("The vid") and ("Meta data for video loaded") as I expected .

Is it a bug of firefox ? How can I avoid this problem ?

---

I just tired `vid.addEventListener("canplay", getmetadata);` and got the same result .
It seems the problem is about 'addEventListener'

---

The video was loaded . I can use vid.play to play it . I also used console.log(vid) to see if the DOM was right , and it was .

It seems addEventListener skip watching "loadedmetadata" and "canplay" , and I don't know why .

---

I just tried .oncanplay and .onloadedmetadata ,and found it was not the addEventListener ,but the Event caused this problem .

While something (e.g. alert()) disturbed the loading , Firefox couldn't get the Event . So if the video came out to be 'On Loadedmetadata' or 'On Canplay' in the moment , firefox didn't catch up it . After that , the video is loadedmetadata or canplay .It's the attributes , not the event .Firefox misses the event , and rushes forward .

Comment: make sure that the video was indeed loaded

Comment: Yes , the video was loaded . I can use vid.play to play it . I also used console.log(vid) to see if the DOM was right , and it was .

Comment: I had the same issue, seems "preload" attribute not working properly. The problem disappears when i called $video.trigger("load") before play it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally I use `console.log(vid.readyState)` and found a solution .

While loading a page , firefox is so fast that it rush in a hurry while chrome and ie are waiting for something .

At the moment `vid.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", getmetadata)` , vid.readyState come out to be more than `2` in firefox , while on chrome and ie , vid.readyState is still `0`.

readyState 0 means 'No information is available about the media resource' .

readyState 2 means 'Data is available for the current playback position, but not enough to actually play more than one frame' , the same like 'loadedmetadata'.It's not an event , but a property.

I changed the code like this to check if the brower rushed too fast to miss the event 'loadedmetadata'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">


  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
alert("The vid");
vid.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", getmetadata);

if (vid.readyState >= 2) {
      getmetadata();
    }

function getmetadata()
{
alert("Meta data for video loaded");
}

</script> 

<p>test</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

For more informaion about readyState : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState

Comment: Finally I found a `async:false` in the file . Try adjusting order to make readystate right .

Comment: This could probably be improved by moving the `addEventListener` into an else under the readyState condition so that it only gets added if the video object isn't ready.  Good solution though!

Comment: After 5 hours trying to get video duration in Next.js I finally found your almost 9 years answer! Thanks!

Comment: Had a similar problem, where I needed the duration of a video but for some reason, the `loadedmetadata` Event didn't fire occasionally. I found your answer and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and got a solution. I used `loadeddata` event instead of `loadedmetadata` event and it worked for me.

In the *Definitive Guide Javascript* book it says `loadeddata` event means:

> Data for the current playback position has loaded for the first time,
>   and `readyState` has changed to `HAVE_CURRENT_DATA`.

And `HAVE_CURRENT_DATA` means:

> Media data for `currentTime` has been loaded, but not enough data has
>   been loaded to allow the media to play. For video, this typically
>   means that the current frame has loaded, but the next one has not.
>   This state occurs at the end of a sound or movie. It has `readyState`
>   property of value `"2"`.

I hope my answer makes it clear:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
  <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

  <script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    alert("The vid");

    // here I used "loadeddata" event and worked very well♥
    vid.addEventListener("loadeddata", getmetadata);

    function getmetadata() {
      alert("Meta data for video loaded");
    }
  </script> 

  <p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```